# Does "malefic rune", possible typo from "tune" in the context?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, literature, typographical-errors

I have been reading a story by Robert Bloch - The feast in the Abbey. I just cannot see how the "rune" can be correct in the following:

> As I thus mused there fell upon my ears the sounds  of sonorous
> chanting that swelled symphonically from  somewhere far below. Its
> measured cadence rose and  fell solemnly as if it were borne from a
> distance incredible to human ears. It was subtly disturbing; I
> could distinguish neither words nor phrases that I  knew, but the
> potent rhythm bewildered me. It welled, a malefic **rune**, fraught with
> insidious, strange  suggestion.

Should not "tune" make sense? However, all references I found read truly "rune", but again all could be using the same, corrupted OCR...

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Rune** is correct. It is used in a figurative sense - a flowing stream

OED:

> **3. A flow of water; a stream, a watercourse. English regional (chiefly south-western) in later use. Cf. rean n., rhine n.3**
>
> OE   Aldhelm Glosses (Brussels 1650) in L. Goossens Old Eng. Glosses of MS Brussels, Royal Libr. 1650 (1974) 186   Perpes aquęductuum decursus : singal renes [read rene] wætertige.
>
> 1849   W. A. Williamson Local Etymol. 96   Rune, a watercourse, a channel, from the Teut. rhennen, to run, flow.

It is a **very** old and rare word.

(You can hear it spoken at about 6:49 in ""The Feast in the Abbey" by Robert Bloch / A HorrorBabble Production"" at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eAf2-99Y0II

Comment: Thanks a lot, I was not able to find this meaning, much appreciated!

Comment: But in that case, how does "malefic" fit the context?

Comment: ? In it's literal meaning.

Comment: @RosieF - "literary - causing harm or destruction, especially by supernatural means."

Comment: _In it's literal meaning_ - is that a Greybeard's apostrophe?

Comment: @MichaelHarvey, Could be 'autocorrect' feature. Which - although useful - can be annoying at times.